# Hard and painful stool in infant - is this normal?

Tags: toddler, infant, potty

On several different occasions my daughter (7mnths-12mnths) was trying to poop, but then she would start crying like she was in pain.

When I checked her diaper she had a big hard fat poop coming out, but it seemed stuck. I've had to actually help her push it out.

Is that normal?  What can I do to help her feel less uncomfortable?

Comment: Hello Sbriss, welcome here. Please remember to give your question a clear title that describes the topic of your question. Is your question really just "is that normal", or are you hoping for hints, how to avoid this in the future? If so, please change the question.

Comment: That's pretty common, especially if the baby has recently started solids. It takes time for the body to adjust to the changes in the diet. 

I don't understand what you mean by "help push it out" -- what have you been doing to "help push it out?"

Comment: Also [How do you identify/relieve/prevent constipation in toddlers?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6571/how-do-you-identify-relieve-prevent-constipation-in-toddlers)

Comment: Hey Sbriss, the answer to "is this normal" is "yes", and answers to the other part of your question can be found in links kindly provided by Joe. Don't take it personally if your question gets closed, we simply don't like to repeat oruselves (and old questions tend to have very thorough and otherwise complete answers).

Comment: I'd add that if you don't find what you need in those questions, clarify that in the comments here or in a question edit (depending on whether it's some additional information you haven't included yet); we can reopen once it's on hold if you need different information than those questions contain.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to our second kid, though I never had to help him get it out.

It is not uncommon for some kids to have hard stool when starting solid.

Initially I would recommend you try to increase her water intake, as that is most often the issue. Make sure she gets water with every meal.

Do not feed bananas, apples and other highly constipating foods.

Try pears, strawberries and plums instead (lots of people will recommend prunes, I have yet to meet anyone who wanted to drink prune juice!)

If this doesn't help, talk to your pediatrician. It may be a dairy or other allergy or reaction (or infant intolerance), or the pediatrician may recommend laxatives. Do NOT give your daughter laxatives or other medication, even over the counter ones, without talking to you doctor.

Comment: I'd add also sufficient fiber - bread, vegetables, etc. all help.